# Inserting into the IDLE history from a script in the IDLE shell

Tags: python, python-idle

I want to be able to push code into the IDLE shell history from a script such that

```
>>>somecode = """
def somefunc():
    pass
"""
>>>idlelib.some_unknown_add_to_history_method(somecode)
>>><ALT-p>
```

Results in:

```
>>>def somefunc():
    pass
```

So that I can edit and re-evaluate somefunc just as if I had manually pasted or entered the code into the shell. Is there an existing way to do this, or will I need to write an IDLE extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDLE does not offer a way to insert an item into its shell history. You could change the code in PyShell.py.

Take a look at the [IdleX](http://idlex.sourceforge.net) project for a lot of examples of IDLE extensions. There's an extension for providing persistent history across IDLE sessions which might be a good starting point for writing your own extension. See PersistentHistory.py from that project.

You might like its SubCode extension which allows you to edit and re-evaluate parts of your code directly from the editor by pressing Ctrl+Enter. You could also highlight code in the editor and run it by pressing F9.